# selecting and deselecting items in a selection-list

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

So in a default selection-list you can select an item then click 'Ctrl' and select more. I was wondering if there is a way to have clicking an item in a selection-list select it or deselect it depending on if it's already selected, no matter if other items are selected. In short get away from using the 'Ctrl' key. Thanks!!

using 10.2b

If I was to use triggers how would I go about starting

Answer (score 0):

Not as a default behavior as far as I know. But it should be possible by using triggers.